# Changing input focus color

Tags: html, css

Kindly tell me how to change the color color of input in CSS.

By default it is blue, i want to change the input border color only,

i tried:

```
input:focus {
outline: none !important;
border:1px solid red;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

my input is

```
#admission input {
height: 18px;
color: #666666;
padding-left: 5px;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

It is working but when it is clicked the input field become a bit smaller
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you need to change :focus box shadow color

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE; // if you want to change the shadow also
border-color: #66afe9;
```

`#719ECE` if shadow color and `#66afe9` border color

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/0c60ppn8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your input: http://jsfiddle.net/j6qdpmeo/